# Can analytic weights be converted into sampling weights?

Tags: weighted-regression, weights, survey-weights

I am running a linear probability model, so I know I need to correct for heteroskedasticity. Since I know the variance of the error (from theory) to be $y(\pmb x)(1-y(\pmb x))$ where $y$ is the dependent variable—a probability—I can do a weighted least squares estimation. First, I will estimate the OLS regression, then I will use the predicted values $\hat y$ to find the variance of each error: $\sigma^2(\hat y(1-\hat y))$.

My textbook indicates that I should "use the weights" $\hat h = \hat y(1-\hat y)$, which was shown as dividing each variable (explanatory and explained) by $\sqrt {\hat h}$. Doing that would take a lot of time, but I have been taught that I can get the computer to do this much more quickly, by telling the computer that $\hat h$ are analytic weights.

My problem is that I am using survey data, so I need to use the sampling weights as well. My computer program (Stata) can't take both weights in in the same command—it only wants one. So, **can I combine the two weights into one?** Can I let, say, $a=1/\sqrt{\hat h}$, then let $w = sa$ where $w$ is the new sampling weight and $s$ was the old sampling weight?